# Using a template in a shared library

Tags: c++, templates, shared-libraries

I'm working on a project, where an application uses shared libraries as plugins.
I'm writing such a plugin and want to use a class with template members which is defined in the code of the main application:

```
class MyClass 
{
public:
    template <class T>
    T* doSomething();
}
```

What I'm wondering now is this:

The main application is compiled first. While doing so, the compiler extends the class definition everytime it encounters a new instantiation of the template member `doSomething()`. The application is linked together as an executable containing `MyClass` with all the different instantiations of the template that the compiler encountered.

Now the shared library (plugin) is compiled. Here, I instantiate a version of the template which was not instantiated in the code of the main application.

Now the plugin and the application have effectively different versions of `MyClass` and I don't see how this could be resolved at compile-time.

What would happen, when the main application is started and it loads the shared library (plugin). What happens if I create an object of the libraries' version of `MyClass` and pass it to the main application - they can't be compatible, right?

Comment: You should export those instantiated template variants either from library into main executable, or from main executable into library so no duplication occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can do this without altering the code of the main application (which is not mine!)

Comment: A plugin is a shared library that is *optionally* loaded by an executable via `dlopen` and got its functions accessed via `dlsym` or equivalent. Is this how you run your plugin? Can you show a code snippet that calls `doSomething`?

Comment: Also I'm wodnering how this can work in general. Right now, plugins already instantiate `MyClass` without neccessarily using all the same instantiations of the template members as the main application. In my understanding, the class compiled in the plugin should already look different than the one of the main application. Yet it works. Why?

Comment: Note that your class is not a template, only member function is. Adding any amount of template functions into class won't really matter unless application uses one of those functions.

Comment: @VTT: Is that because, in the memory layout the template function is basically something like a global function receiving a `this` pointer - thus an object instantiated in the library looks identical to the main application because its memory layout is the same (member variables are untouched, after all). That would mean `MyClass::doSomething<T>` (with this instantiation of the template not occuring in the main app) sits somewhere in the plugins library binary and is actually not bound to the memory layout if an object of `MyClass`?

Comment: In c++ member functions are never bound to the memory layout of the object.

Comment: If you can't statically link your main app with your shared library, I don't think you'll be able to do this.

Comment: okay, this solves it for me - thank you. Am I supposed to add an answer on my own? IIRC I can't accept my own answers yet, though